# How are Seasonal Adventure points obtained in Minecraft Dungeons?

Tags: minecraft-dungeons

Seasonal Adventures are themed events in *Minecraft Dungeons*. Completing weekly challenges let you earn **Adventure Points** to unlock rewards.

So far so good.

According to [Minecraft official site](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4416089241997-Minecraft-Dungeons-Seasonal-Adventures-FAQ):

> Adventure Points are **gained through regular gameplay** or by completing weekly challenges in the game. Adventure Points and Adventure Rank must be **gained through gameplay** and cannot be purchased.

[image]

Now, I get that completing a weekly challenge gives me Adventure points, of course. But what exactly "regular gameplay" mean? Do I get points while "filling" the challenge counter? Do missions completed count towards that? Or maybe opening chests?

I don't understand what's the best way to gain points besides the challenges. We only get 5 of them weekly, it looks like a very long journey to level 50...

Any hint?

Comment: I usually don't care about these things, but level 46 drop is required for a trophy... how evil is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of hours spent in this game, and considering the latest update which introduced Season 2 and kinda balanced the system, these actions increase Seasonal Adventure points:

- Complete The Tower on any difficult (worths a lot!)
- Complete a weekly challenge (you gain points while progressing them, not all at once when completed)
- Complete a dungeon
- Complete an Ancient Hunt
- Defeat a boss
- Defeat a Raid captain
- Open a chest